# Best way to transfer data from Arduino to Server

Tags: arduino, gsm, arduino-ide

I am new to Arduino and I would like to do a project that sends data, remotely.  So, the Arduino would not be connected to Wifi/Bluetooth, Ethernet, etc.  Would using a GSM shield be the best way to transfer data?  I do not need to make phone calls or send SMS (unless sending SMS would be a better, more reliable, option) just data to a server, who's app I would create.  If this is the best option, what else would I need to make this happen?  For example, on top of the GSM shield (I am looking at something cheap like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Geeetech-SIMCOM-Quad-band-Development-Arduino/dp/B00A8DDYB6/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1467651878&sr=8-2&keywords=Arduino+GSM+Shield](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A8DDYB6)) what other charges would I need to pay?  I.E. would I also need to get another phone plan?  Would I have to pay for a gateway service that would receive the cell phone data and then send it to my server?

Thanks your any thoughts on this

Answer (score 0):

Wifi, ethernet or GSM, it depends on what you want to use, and what you have.
With all three you can send data to a server.

There is a bench of Arduino shields. All shields from Arduino come with a library to handle communication.

Other shields from other vendors exist and they provide their libraries too.

For `Ethernet` you can check the arduino shield https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet.

For `Wifi` there are plenty. You have first the arduino shield. You can also take a look at the `CC3000`. Or the famous `ESP8266`. For all three you can find libraries.

For `GSM`, Arduino has a shield and a library. Arduino uses the `Quectel M10` GSM moduel. You can find lots of examples in the arduino website and all over the net (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoGSMShield).

There exist other shields like the one you mentioned. Libraries does exist for those "other" shields however they are not as maintained as the arduino one.

You need to be careful though, you'll find over Amazon (and most likely on Alibaba) some GSM modules like SIM900**A** that are way cheaper, those are only dual band and will work **only** on certain contries.

There is another cheap GSM Module called the **A6**. It was made by *espressif* the company behid the `ESP8266`. It's relatively new and no library exist for it at the time. You can write you own functions to use it, but that would be some extra work.

In all cases, to use a GSM module you'll need a sim card with it's phone plan and all.

Another thing to consider is how to power these shields. They use more power than an Arduino can generate (A GSM modules datasheet recommend to use a power supply that can deliver up to 2A). If you power them straight from the Arduino, you may encounter some strange behaviour.
So the ideal way is to have for them an external power supply with the required amps and have a commun ground with the Arduino.